# strange behavior or ^ operator in c# and vb,net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

In C# `Console.WriteLine(16 ^ 2);` gives me `18`

but in VB.Net `Console.WriteLine(16 ^ 2)` gives me `256`

Why so ?

Comment: That's no strange behavior, it's a false assumption.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C# ^ is a bitwise XOR operator. [C# ^ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zkacc7k1.aspx)

So if you represent 16 in bits you have

```
10000
```

And 2 is

```
00010
```

XOR means that you get 1 if only one of the operands has a 1 in the corresponding place:

```
 10000
+00010
=10010
```

Which translates to 18.

In VB it is the power operator. [VB ^ Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zh100ckf%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you raise 16 with a power of 2 as if you had:

```
16 * 16 = 256
```

Comment: FYI (16 ^ 2) in c# is actually bitwise XOR not logical XOR

Comment: then why it gives me 18 in `C#`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx sais it is a Logical XOR operator

Comment: @jyparask Pls check in same link ` For integral types, ^ computes the bitwise exclusive-OR of its operands. For bool operands, ^ computes the logical exclusive-or of its operands;`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Well, i guess we agree... If you check my example this is a bitwise XOR operation. In my mind i was having Logical as in each bit of the binary representation of the two operands, so each bit was either true (1) or false (0). But you are right in that, so i will change my statement.

Comment: @jyparask and your example is wrong. `00001 = 1` **00010 = 2**, **10001 = 17 not 18**

Comment: Duhh... you are right, i was quick to write it...

Comment: Change it, then you'll own my vote

Answer (score 2):

There is `Math.Pow(x, y)` function in C#.

But in VB.NET ^ is used directly to indicate power as we do in simple mathematics.